# extra space in first item in list view?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have extra space in my listview in the first time  because of the divider .

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/layout_bg_wallet_login"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop ="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>
```

I know the culprit is the divide which is image with spaces at top and bottom . But i do not need empty space at the top because of my divider .

I tried setting divider height to zero in adapter when position ==0 but does not work . The divider is missing after the first item . HOw to solve this strange issue in listview .

Comment: The divider only exists _between_ rows... Could you post a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Comment: I have no clue , if i remove the android divider then extra space between the first item and header vanishes . The divider may come into picture because i have a header as well .

Comment: I think screenshot would help us understand your exact problem. And if you are sure that its due to your divider image, just try editing that image. Remove space that is at top of the image.